# Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, server, port

I am trying to develope a webapp using spring boot in STS. While running my app i am getting

**Description:**

> Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

**Action:**

> Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or
> configure this application to listen on another port.

I have tried to close the application for port 8080. I found the PID for the port and terminated it using

```
taskkill /F /PID pidname
```

I restarted the STS and tried to run again but its throwing the same error.

Comment: What application was it? It might be configured as a service in your operating system. That means that it gets restarted automatically, so stopping it once is not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If port is acquired by some OS thread, it would be a bit tricky to stop it. Although it's not always great solution, but if you still want to continue with your development without any issue you can use this alternative solution (as you are in development environment).

Here is another thing you can use. You can replace the default port for Spring Boot server to some other port number.

For server port the property is `server.port`.

If you are using `application.properties` file:

```
server.port=8081
```

It will start server on port 8081.

Similarly, you can do the same if using an `application.yml` file:

```
server:
  port : 8081
```

Each file is loaded by Spring Boot if placed in the `src/main/resources` directory of a Maven application.

Comment: Agree without wasting much time in finding the other application running on same port. That time can be used in development efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Your only other option (beside making port 8080 available or using another port for spring boot) is running the application in docker:

Create a Dockerfile in your application directory

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Run in terminal

```
sudo docker build -t spring-app . && docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -t springapp
```

(This assumes you have docker installed, please install it if you don’t have it)